# Unable to create codestar host

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

I am trying to create a host on code pipeline. I am getting "Vpc configuration initialization failed" error.

I can access GitHub instance through an ec2 instance that is on the same subnet with vpc configuration. Also that ec2 instance has same security group with vpc configuration.

When I look at the throubleshooting documentation [Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dtconsole/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-connections.html#troubleshooting-connections-host-vpc-failed) in the "I’m unable to get a host in pending state" there is a check list and I believe my configuration is covers all of them.

Can I see more detailed error log and if I can where I can see it? cause now I don't know if its a permission or connection error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out why I am having this problem. The vpc where you create host should have enable dns resolution and enable dns hostnames set to true.